How to visualize the pydrake iiwa example using Drake?
I tried to visualize the pydrake iiwa manipualtion station with the following code but failed with error:

RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder does not contain a subsystem named plant

How to make the visualization work in this case?
from pydrake.multibody.parsing import  Parser
from pydrake.examples import ManipulationStation
from pydrake.geometry import StartMeshcat
from pydrake.visualization import AddDefaultVisualization
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder

station = ManipulationStation()
parser = Parser(station.get_mutable_multibody_plant(),
                station.get_mutable_scene_graph())
builder = DiagramBuilder()
builder.AddSystem(station)
meshcat = StartMeshcat()
AddDefaultVisualization(builder=builder, meshcat=meshcat)


The ManipulationStation example in Drake has fallen a bit out of date with our best practices. In my manipulation notes, I've replaced this with a MakeHardwareStation workflow, which is described in this chapter: https://manipulation.mit.edu/robot.html#hardware_station . I strongly recommend using it instead of Drake's ManipulationStation example.
The MakeHardwareStation adds the default visualization automatically, so there is no need to add it yourself.
